# Center text in color box

Tags: horizontal-alignment, color

I wanto to center a text in a colorbox which is scaled horicontal over the complete site.

[image]

How is this possible?

```
\documentclass[
]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[
]{scrpage2}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}                 %% Deutsches Sprachpaket
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                 %% Eingabezeichensatz UTF-8
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}                    %% Kodierung für Umlaute
\usepackage[ngerman]{translator}            %% Für Abkürzungsverzeichnis benötigt
\usepackage{lmodern}                        %% Moderne Version von Computer Modern
\usepackage{setspace}                       %% Zeileabstand anpassen
\usepackage{xcolor}                         %% Definieren von Farben

\begin{document}

\chapter{}
\definecolor{lightgray}{gray}{0.5}
\newcommand \colbox [1]{\par\noindent\colorbox{gray}{\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}{ {#1}} \hfill \end{minipage}}}

\colbox{TEXT}

\end{document}
```

Moreover I want to avoid the overfull hbox.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Tried putting `\hfill <stuff> \hfill` in your `tcolorbox`?

Comment: @1010011010: There is no `tcolorbox` information given...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a full width `\parbox` after taking account the padding added by `\colorbox`:

```
\noindent
\colorbox{grey}{\parbox{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\fboxsep}{\centering
 hello
}}
```

Comment: Is it possible to use \verbatim in the text section? Because I wanto to write a command there.

Comment: @Martin well not directly but there are several answers showing how to put verbatim in a box, but you presumably don't mean verbatim (as you can't center that as it is full width) if you just want a line such as in your question you don't need verb just `\texttt{\$ git clone ...}` would do.